# perl substitute multiple lines

Tags: perl, matching, substitution

I have a file which looks like:

```
<QUERY name="Secondary">
            <SQLStmt>select * from my_tb;
            </SQLStmt>
<QUERY name="primary">
            <SQLStmt>select * from my_tb;
            </SQLStmt>

<QUERY name="last">
            <SQLStmt>select * from my_tb;
            </SQLStmt>
```

I need to substitute the SQLStmnts with some other SQLStmnts and Query name I received from commandline.

How can I use a condition to match and substitute?

```
$qury_nm=shift;
$sqlstmt=shift;
undef $/;
if(/<QUERY name="$qury_nm">(.*)<SQLStmt>(.*)<\SQLStmt>/)
{
  #need help here!!
   substitute the matched qury_nms SQLStmt wth the $sqlstmt and write it into the same file...
}
```

Comment: http://codepad.org/ekwVuA5U 
pls see this link for a better view

Comment: I don't think that the "push" command does what you think it does :-)

Comment: ooh ..it should be shift instead of push...
changed it :)

Answer (score 2):

XML is not a regular language.  [You should not treat it as such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).  Use one of the fine XML parsers available for Perl.  A good way might be to use XML::Twig.  Here is a tutorial: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/03/21/xmltwig.html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to go :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use 5.10.1;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $qury_nm = 'primary';
my $sqlstmt = 'SELECT col1,col2 FROM table2';
undef $/;
my $str = <DATA>;

$str =~ s!(<QUERY name="$qury_nm">.*?<SQLStmt>).*?(</SQLStmt>)!$1$sqlstmt$2!s;
say $str;

__DATA__
<QUERY name="Secondary">
            <SQLStmt>select * from my_tb;
            </SQLStmt>
<QUERY name="primary">
            <SQLStmt>select * from my_tb;
            </SQLStmt>

<QUERY name="last">
            <SQLStmt>select * from my_tb;
            </SQLStmt>
```

Output:

```
<QUERY name="Secondary">
            <SQLStmt>select * from my_tb;
            </SQLStmt>
<QUERY name="primary">
            <SQLStmt>SELECT col1,col2 FROM table2</SQLStmt>

<QUERY name="last">
            <SQLStmt>select * from my_tb;
            </SQLStmt>
```